# EF Core 7 saves changes line by line for list less than 4 entities

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, savechanges

I am newbie in .NET and EF Core 7 and can't understand this behaviour.

I have this .NET code:

```
...
List<UsersGroups> ugs = new List<UsersGroups>();
DateTime ddd = DateTime.Now;

foreach (string group in Groups)
{
    if (some condition)
    {
        ADGroups adGroup = await _context.ADGroups.FirstAsync(group => group.Name.Contains(groupName));
        ugs.Add(new UsersGroups{ DateCheck = ddd, UserId = ManId, Action = "Login", GroupId = adGroup.Id });
    }
}

_context.UsersGroups.AddRange(ugs);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The SQL Server table for `_context.UsersGroups` has a trigger after insert with notification:

```
DECLARE @message NVARCHAR(500) = (SELECT *, spid = @@SPID, t = SYSDATETIME() FROM INSERTED FOR JSON AUTO)

EXEC [dbo].[SendNotify] @message
```

The problem is: if there are less than 4 objects in `List<UsersGroups> ugs`, the call to `await _context.SaveChangesAsync()` makes one change on each object. So trigger fires on each object but not for array. But if there are 4 or more objects in the list, everything is OK - trigger fires once for the whole batch.

Results of inserts:

2 objects in List = 2 messages:

```
[ { "Id": 6566, "UserId": 163, "GroupId": 1, "spid": 66,"t": "2024-01-29T11:10:29.4294982" } ]
[ { "Id": 6567, "UserId": 163, "GroupId": 2, "spid": 66,"t": "2024-01-29T11:10:29.6303315" } ]
```

4 and more objects = `BatchInsert`

```
[
  { "Id": 6571, "UserId": 163, "GroupId": 3, "spid": 66,"t": "2024-01-29T11:11:05.3763680" }, 
  { "Id": 6570, "UserId": 163, "GroupId": 2, "spid": 66,"t":"2024-01-29T11:11:05.3763680" },
  { "Id": 6569, "UserId": 163, "GroupId": 1, "spid": 66, "t": "2024-01-29T11:11:05.3763680" },
  { "Id": 6568, "UserId": 163, "GroupId": 9, "spid": 66,"t":"2024-01-29T11:11:05.3763680" } 
]
```

How to make `_context.SaveChangesAsync()` make one call to SQL Server for 2 and 3 objects?

Comment: I believe there was a time when EF was sending 1 request per inserted entity no matter how much entities were inserted. I would guess that if you will try to insert  much more than 4 entities then EF can start chunking the  batches. Arguably you should not make assumptions how exactly EF will insert your data. Note that EF should wrap such chunked inserts into a transaction (as the one with 2 rows).

Comment: There is some information: [What's New in EF Core 7.0 - Faster SaveChanges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/whatsnew#faster-savechanges)

Comment: See [Batching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-updating?tabs=ef7#batching) topic in EFC official docs. Basically you need to set MinBatchSize to 1 (default for SqlServer is 5) when configuring db context options -  [MinBatchSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.relationaldbcontextoptionsbuilder-2.minbatchsize?view=efcore-8.0) method

Comment: @GuruStron you wrote "Arguably you should not make assumptions how exactly EF will insert your data". I think it is a bad idea. No framework can write the most efficient sql query. And when someone add 2 rows at once, I must see that fact.

Comment: @АлександрЕмельянов 1) I have not written that you shouldn't care, I have said that you should not make assumptions. 2) _"And when someone add 2 rows at once"_ - if two rows are inserted in one transaction but in separate requests is this "at once"?

Comment: @АлександрЕмельянов also note that there is a quite  strong opinion that triggers should be avoided in general.

Comment: @IvanStoev, спасибо - почитал. Попробовал так `builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<ErpDBContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ErpDb"), options => options.MinBatchSize(1)), ServiceLifetime.Scoped);` - не спасло. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: @АлександрЕмельянов in English please)

Comment: @АлександрЕмельянов You are welcome. And yes, this is correct configuration (as soon as you don't have something inside `OnConfiguring` in your db context which overrides it), and is expected to work by batching 2+ INSERT commands into single MERGE command. Hmm, are your [informing EF that your table has tringger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes?tabs=v7#sqlserver-tables-with-triggers)? Most probably yes, because that's the only way I can reproduce the described behavior.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, we have OnConfiguring. And it seems to be normal - Options.Extensions."SqlServerOptionsExtension".MinBatchSize = 1. But still don't batch two objects :(

Comment: @IvanStoev arguably if EF knowing about triggers was the issue EF would not batch higher amounts of inserted rows.

Comment: @АлександрЕмельянов can you please add queries which are generated and executed by EF for both cases?

Comment: @GuruStron There must be a bug or something in EFC 7.x/8.x. I was able to reproduce it. Just create a simple entity and tell EF that it has fake trigger (`.HasTrgigger("Blah")`), then even if you specify `MinBatchSize(1)` or regardless, for adding N < 4 I'm getting N `INSERT` commands, and for N >= 4 it is single `MERGE` EFC6 syntax. So one is what you think/is logical/expected, another is what you get :-( I have no time to investigate their GitHub, but for sure the OP explained behavior exists.

Comment: It turned out the value 4 is intentional. Here is the source code https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/451514e2e8887b3ee56062b241386d66aeabffc7/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Update/Internal/SqlServerUpdateSqlGenerator.cs#L34 value 4 causing that behavior. Check its usage along with `CanUseOutputClause` (which has something to do with triggers) if you are interested of getting their SQL generation logic. All I get is the comment for value 4 "Below this threshold, multiple batched INSERT statements are more efficient." :)

Comment: @IvanStoev thanks for research. Could you post an answer with last comment so I can accept it?